# References for understanding the topic: Invariant Einstein metrics

Tags: reference-request, manifolds, lie-groups

I would like to learn what prerequisites are needed in order to be able to work on a postgraduate thesis on the topic: Invariant Einstein metrics on compact simple Lie groups and Stiefel manifolds.

I have noted Lie groups, differentiable manifolds, general theory of relativity, and tensor analysis.